# Is it possible to securely delete data from memcached?

Tags: security, memcached

As above really, if I store something (e.g. website session data) in memcached, is it possible to remove the data securely so that it would not be evident in a later memory dump?

I assume delete just unassigns the memory rather than wiping it? Could I manually junk the allocated memory by updating the key with random data before deleting it?

Obviously encrypting the data before storing it would be a solution but this also adds a performance overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ#Why_Isn%27t_curr_items_Decreasing_When_Items_Expire?). So, if you want to secure your data, because you are in a hostile environment, use SASL authentication. [Check it out: SASL](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLHowto)

And make sure no one has access to memcached from the outside!!! Bind it to localhost.

Excerpt from the manual:

> **When do expired cached items get deleted from the cache?**
>
> memcached uses a lazy expiration, which means it uses no extra cpu
>   expiring items. When an item is requested (a get request) it checks
>   the expiration time to see if the item is still valid before returning
>   it to the client.
>
> Similarly when adding a new item to the cache, if the cache is full,
>   it will look at for expired items to replace before replacing the
>   least used items in the cache.

Answer (score 3):

You can't... Replacing a value is another allocation and will not overwrite the old value in memory.